# React state gets resetted after rerendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, react-functional-component

I am new to React and facing an issue with updating the state of a functional component.

I have a component `TinderCards.js` like below, which basically takes in a list of objects from a context provider and for each object, creates a `TinderCard`  (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tinder-card) which is supposed to update the `count` when swiped (`onSwipe`).

However, what happens is that every time a card gets swiped, the `count` gets increased to 1 and then doesn't go any further.

E.g.

> Initial count value: 0

> Swipe first card => count = 1

> Swipe second card => count = 1 (should be 2)

> Swipe third card => count = 1 (should be 3)

I have tried including the `count` value as both part of the Component's state and as part of a global context called `ResultsContext.js`, but both lead to the same behaviour.

**NOTE** that the button with class `test-btn` behaves EXACTLY how I want at `onClick`. However, the `onSwipe` for the `TinderCard` Component doesn't, even though it's basically the same code and it's driving me crazy.

*TinderCards.js*

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import TinderCard from "react-tinder-card";
import StocksContext from "./StocksContext";
import ResultsContext from "./ResultsContext";
import "./Tindercards.css";

function TinderCards(props) {
  // const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const { count, setCount } = useContext(ResultsContext);
  const { stocks, setStocks } = useContext(StocksContext);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="tinderCards__cardContainer">
        <div>
          Count: {count}
          <button className="test-btn" onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Increment</button>
        </div>
        <div className="main__container">
          {stocks.map((stock) => (
            <TinderCard
              onSwipe={() => setCount(count + 1)}
              className="swipe"
              key={stock.name}
              preventSwipe={["up", "down"]}
            >
              <div className="card">
                <div style={{ height: "100%" }}>
                  <img
                    src={stock.url}
                    style={{
                      objectFit: "contain",
                      height: "100%",
                      width: "100%",
                      backgroundColor: "white",
                    }}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <h3 style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}>${stock.name}</h3>
            </TinderCard>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TinderCards;
```

I appreciate any help! Thank you very much!

Comment: hi, please read up https://github.com/3DJakob/react-tinder-card/issues/21. seems like related to your issue above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `count` variable inside the `onSwipe` handler(s):

```
() => setCount(count + 1)
```

is a closure that contains the value of `count` at the point they were rendered - which is 0. One of those functions running doesn't actually change the value of the `count` variable - it simply triggers a rerender of the parent component. Those other children still retain their `onSwipe` handler that simply sets the count to 2 (1 more than the value of `count` when they were rendered) - which is what you're seeing.

The simple solution here is to pass an [update function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) to `setCount`, rather than a hardcoded value:

```
onSwipe={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)}
```

This will ensure that the "latest value" of the `count` state is always read, and incremented by 1.

Comment: Out of curiosity though, why was the `test-btn` working perfectly without having to do that? Appreciate it!

Comment: Good question - and I'm really not sure, assuming you mean by "working perfectly" that it always increases the count by 1 even after you've swiped some of the "TinderCards" too. I would expect the same issue there. (I hadn't spotted that in your code when I wrote my answer.)

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant - it was increasing by 1 every time I swipped a card. Thanks a lot for your help rly appreciate it!